# How to check if two int arrays are permutations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, permutation

How can I check if two integers `arrays` are ***permutations***? I need to do it in JavaScript.

For example, I have two arrays:

`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

and

`b = [2, 3, 5, 1, 4]`

I need the program to return `true`.

Comment: Can we see your current code attempt?

Comment: A permutation is *by definition* the same objects but in different order. Therefore, check if the two arrays contain the same items regardless of their positions.

Comment: Sorting the arrays will probably make things easier.

Comment: i checked if the two arrays contain the same items regardless of their position but when there will be duplicates it wont work ;/

Comment: if i add "4" to the firs array and "5" to the second one the result is still true

Comment: `const isPermutation = (a,b) => a.length === b.length && a.every(x=> b.indexOf(x) > -1)`

Answer (score 2):

The lazy solution:

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5],
    b = [2,3,5,1,4];

let res = JSON.stringify(a.sort()) === JSON.stringify(b.sort())

console.log(res)
```

The more efficient solution:

```js
function perm (a,b) {
  let map = a.reduce((acc,c) => {acc[c] = (acc[c] || 0) + 1; return acc},{})
  for (el of b) {
    if (!map[el] || map[el] == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      map[el]--;
    }
  }
  for (k in map) {
    if (map[k] != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(perm([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 5, 1, 4])) // => true
console.log(perm([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5],[2, 3, 5, 1, 4])) // => false
console.log(perm([1,1,2],[1,2,2])) // => false
console.log(perm([1,2,3,4,5,1],[2,3,1,5,1,4])) // => true
```

This solution is in hindsight similar to the one of @trincot but I guess slightly different enough to keep it posted.

The idea is the following: We create a map from the first array via `reduce` where the value is a count of occurrences. We then take the other array and subtract occurrences from the respective keys of map. If the key doesn't exist is or the value is already zero, we know this is not a permutation. Afterwords we loop the map, checking whether all values are exactly zero.

Comment: Although the OP mentioned "integers", be aware that `JSON.stringify` converts NaN, -Infinity and Infinity (all of which are numbers) to "null".

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Map` to store the occurrence count and then decrease that count whenever you find a mapping occurrence in the other array:

```js
function isPermutation(a, b) {
    if (a.length !== b.length) return false;
    let map = new Map(a.map(x => [x, { count: 0 }]));
    a.forEach(x => map.get(x).count++);
    return b.every(x => {
         let match = map.get(x);
         return match && match.count--;
    });
}

let a =[1,2,3,4,5,1];
let b = [2,3,1,5,1,4];
console.log(isPermutation(a, b));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = [2, 3, 5, 1, 4];
return a.filter(x => !b.includes(x)).length === 0
```

This will return true if all of the values in `a` exists in `b`, regardless of position.

Comment: What about duplicates ?

Comment: @Titus, how do you mean?

Comment: @AAA `var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]; var b = [2, 3, 5, 1, 4];`

Comment: This will fail if the arrays contain duplicates, for example: `[1,1,2]` and `[1,2,2]`

Comment: yes, i tried it but it wont work with duplicates ;/

Comment: @AAA That is my point, this solution will return `true` for the example arrays in my previous comment, [here is an snippet](https://jsbin.com/ruvolorexe/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Titus, I see your point. Thanks. Any reason why `console.log(a.sort().toString() === b.sort().toString())` is a bad idea? I mean, if we take OP's word that both a and b are integer arrays... It worked for me....

Comment: @AAA That should work but there seem to be more efficient ways of doing it like **trincot**'s solution which uses `Map`s to get rid of sorting.

Comment: Yup, true! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```js
var a =[1,2,3,4,5,1];
var b = [2,3,1,5,1,4];
console.log(a.sort().toString() === b.sort().toString())
```

Comment: Sorting and conversion to string are neither the most efficient operations to choose from.

Comment: @VLAZ, OP said they are arrays of integers. So the case you give cannot arise.